# convergent series and raabe's test

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Show that there exists $N\in \mathbb{N}$ and $C>1$ such that $\displaystyle \frac{2n+4}{2n+1}>1+\frac{C}{n}$ for all $n>N$.

I got this problem while trying to show that a given series converges by Raabe's test. Can anyone please help me to show this?

Answer (score 1):

$\frac{2n+4}{2n+1} = \frac{(2n+1) + 3}{4} = 1 + \frac{3}{2n+1} \geq 1 + \frac{3}{2n+\frac{1}{2}n} = 1 + \frac{6}{5}\frac{1}{n}$ for all $n \geq 2$.

Answer (score 0):

we have $\frac{2n+4}{2n+1}=\frac{2n+1+3}{2n+1}=1+\frac{3}{2n+1}$ therefore we have
$\frac{3}{2n+1}>\frac{C}{n}$ this is equivalent to
$3n>C(2n+1)$
$n(3-2C)>C$
thus $n>\frac{C}{3-2C}$